# Regex to match URL route

Tags: regex

I'm writing a regex to match a route with the pattern `/events/awesome-schema/value2/1`.

The values could be described as:

```
/events >> static part
awesome-schema >> could be any char, number, _ or -
value2 >> could be any char, number, _ or -
1 >> one or more digit
```

For now, I have wrote the following syntax `^/events/([a-z]+[0-9_-]*)/?([a-z]+[0-9_-]*)?/?(\d+)?$` but it's failing.

Any idea why is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `([a-z]+[0-9_-]*)/?([a-z]+[0-9_-]*)?` matches until the slash before `/value2`.

The following `(\d+)?` would not match the `v` from value, which is possible as it is optional, but the `$` anchor that follows makes the pattern not match the whole string as `value2/1` is not matched.

---

You might use

```
^/events/[a-z0-9_]+(?:-[a-z0-9_]+)*/[a-z0-9+_]+/[0-9]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `/events/` Match literally
- `[a-z0-9_]+` Match 1+ times any of `[a-z0-9_]`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `-[a-z0-9_]+` Match `-` and 1+ times any of `[a-z0-9_]`
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `/[a-z0-9+_]+` Match `/` and 1+ times any of `[a-z0-9_]`
- `/[0-9]+` match `/` and 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/34KK8b/1)

If the parts should start with a lowercase as in your original pattern and a match like `awesome-schema--` is also possible , you can start the match with `[a-z]` and use `[a-z0-9_-]*` for the character class.

```
^/events/[a-z][a-z0-9_-]*/[a-z][a-z0-9+_]*/[0-9]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mEklHD/1)

Comment: What it `+(?:-[a-z0-9_]+) ` means?

Comment: This part `[a-z0-9_]+(?:-[a-z0-9_]+)*` will match 1 or more times `[a-z0-9_]+` and then repeats 0+ times `(?:-[a-z0-9_]+)` to that the hyphen can not be at the start or end.

Comment: And \w allow uppercases, I would like to have only lower cases

Comment: @placplacboom I have added an explanation for the pattern.

Comment: Nice explaination. I learn a lot from your answers here =). Why would you not want to allow a `-` at start or end, but `_` is fine? Does that have to do with validation of URL?

Comment: @JvdV Thank you for your comment. Honestly, it is an assumption to match `awesome-schema` and not `awesome-schema--` I have added an update.

Answer (score 1):

It fail because `([a-z]+[0-9_-]*)` will match as much lower case letter as it can, than only `[0-9_-]` these characters could match. Which will match the `-`, but the remaining string is `schema/value2/1` but your pattern try to match `/` char now, but the next character is the character `s` at this point in your example.

This fix it `^/events/([a-z0-9_-]*)/([a-z0-9_-]*)/(\d+)$`

Comment: Note that the character classes are optional and could also possibly match `/events///1`